# Holomorphic functions are Harmonic and Vice Versa

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

If a function $f=u+iv$ is holomorphic $\rightarrow$ Cauchy Riemann eqns hold.

$u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ This means that $u_{xx}=v_{yx}$ and $u_{yy}=-v_{xy}$

At the same time $v_{yy}=u_{xy}$ and $v_{xx}=-u_{yx}$.

This implies: $$u_{xx}+u{yy}+v_{xx}+v_{yy}=0$$ Hence, holomorphic $\Rightarrow$ harmonic. This is useful because harmonic functions attain maximums and minimums at the boundary and I can use max/min modulus principles.

> Is this correct? If $g$ is holomorphic

$g(0)=0$ implies that $|g(0)|=0 \Rightarrow g(z)=0$

**Next,**
All harmonic functions are holomorphic, which is harder to show.
Is this true?

Comment: Don't confuse the attributes of $f$ with those of $u,v$.

Comment: isnt $f_{xx}=u_{xx}+iv_{xx}$?

Comment: Your proof of harmonicity is incorrect. You don't want to add up all those partials. You need $u_{xx}+u_{yy} = 0,$ same for $v.$ And harmonic functions are almost never holomorphic. Example: $u(x,y)=x.$

Comment: @zhw I see, but holomorphic do imply harmonic, I just need a better proof , thanks!